# Get only author defined CSS with JavaScript

Tags: javascript, css

`window.getComputedStyle` gives us all CSS rules applied to an element. I want to get only user-defined styles with JavaScript or CSS, whether they are inline, in a separate file, or inside a style tag. And ignore browsers default styles

Comment: I don't know that this is possible. You're probably better off using `getComputedStyle()` and then try to account for the default styles.

Comment: It's certainly doable, back in the day before dev-tools were built-in into browsers, firebug was able to do it all from JS. you can still find [their sources](https://github.com/firebug/firebug) and grab the code. IIRC they basically did get all the active stylesheets in doc, computed the selectors's specificity and grabbed which rule currently applied.

Answer (score 0):

If you do not use CSS rules applied to elements directly, You can compare the output of the DIV (or other element) in question with a newly created element with browser defaults.

```
window.getComputedStyle(document.createElement("div"))
```

If you use these (anyway not recommended) it will not work

```
div {
color:blue;
}
```

Comment: For new created element every style is empty

Answer (score 0):

This is not realistic to do. Because, for example, set `color` will overwrite a number of properties by default except for `color`. Look at this example:

```js
const div = document.createElement('div');
document.body.append(div);
const browserStyles = window.getComputedStyle(div);

const myDivStyles = window.getComputedStyle(myDiv);

const styles = {};

for (const prop in browserStyles) {
  if (browserStyles[prop] !== myDivStyles[prop]) {
    styles[prop] = myDivStyles[prop];
  }
}

console.log(styles);
```

```html
<div id="myDiv" style="color: red;"></div>
```

Comment: Weird example, that's just because `currentColor` gets computed to the actual current color, but all these properties did not "change".

Comment: when we adding for example border-radius, browser adds borderTop borderLeft webkit etc. all of border types by default with value of border-radius. seems we need bunch of helper functions

Comment: @Kaiido That's why I chose the `color` property to show that not only `color` is actually added directly. And it will not be possible to distinguish whether someone only added `color`.

Comment: But these color related values **have not been changed**, only their computed value has been, but then even the computed value of `div { width: 100% }` will not be `100%` but the `px` size it computes to at the time the `.width` getter is called. That only proves that `getComputedStyle()` is not the correct tool for the task, but nothing in the question implied it could be a good tool for this task. For instance you'd probably get better results looking at `Element#computedStyleMap()` instead (even if I'm not sure it's entirely doable from just there either).